# I made a bounty on VP's SE. What happens if no one answers it?

Tags: support, bounty

I set a bounty on one of my questions. It doesn't seem to get any response.

What will happen if the question won't get any answer or none is satisfying?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bounty goes away and the rep disappears.  The bounty is for getting the extra attention.  I've personally never been a huge fan of how it works, but that's the way it is setup.

Comment: Hey AJ, thank you. Well. I got 1 more view through it until now... And I'm not even sure if it isn't myself... If it stays like that, it really was a big waste .-.

Comment: I took a look at it and hadn't previously.  Unfortunately I'm not sure about the details of that lens.  Unless someone feels like doing some research on it, I doubt you'll find someone who knows it off the top of their head.  I'm unfortunately too busy lately to be able to dig in to it for you.

Comment: Sure. I made a bit of research myself and only thing I found is the supposedly shot on FF image. I'm not sure if the lines are correct. This would purely be a mathematic thing to do and check it